# Is it better to wrap complex dynamic content in Nuxt with client-only?

Tags: nuxt.js

We are using Nuxt.js for a web-based app (in universal mode) and have some quite complex reports that are requested from our server.

These reports take several seconds to generate and are only available if logged in (so no need for SEO-optimisation).

Should we, by default, wrap these reports in `<client-only>`?

There is no benefit as far as I understand of pre-rendering the HTML, and I guess that there is a risk of sending two requests to the server, one from the server-side of Nuxt and another from the client.

Is it worth going through our app and wrapping all dynamic content like this? Are there likely any disadvantages of doing this?

Would anyone be able to enlighten me on best practice here?